# How to configure nginx to serve static files and index.html for everything else for single page app

Tags: nginx, single-page-application

I am building a SPA that serves static files using nginx as a web server. I need a way to serve the root index.html file some routes:

- /spa/route
- /otheroute/
- /test
- /another/one/

but still allow static files to be served.

I have tried many methods and none have done the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have an `nginx.conf` like this (I've taken this from one of my old angular projects):

```
server {
    ## Your website name goes here.
    server_name example.com;

    ## Your only path reference.
    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

    ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.html;

    autoindex off;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
        }
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

The first and the second `location` rules are for common files that don't require any special check and are requested from bots and browsers frequently.

The third rule says that if the requested file (the relative url) doesn't exists, the `index.html` will be served. This file is the main file of your SPA. The `break` keyword will stop the process if this rule matches the request.

The last rule says that if the requested file ends with js, css, png,... (your static assets), it will be server *as is*, without any rewriting.
In this way you can have your assets in any directory without troubles.

P.S. I've used this also with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in my angular app to have *real-looking* urls, and its works nicely.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. This worked for routes like /foo and /user, but not for longer routes such as /foo/bar. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: The problem turned out to be the front end trying to load some files with relative URL's, which caused them to load the index.html with some routes!